# Authentication in django for both web and mobile

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have django website running with django-allauth authentication.
Now, I am planning to build a mobile app using already existing django as a backend.
If there is a way I can continue using django-allauth as authentication for mobile app ?
What is the standard way to implement authentication in django for both web and mobile ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build a restful api that your mobile application makes use of. It comes with support for [OAuth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-rest-framework-oauth).

Comment: Thank you @ohlr! 
Django Rest Framework offers session and (non-expiring) token authentications. Which of them should I use for web and mobile at the same time ? 
Also, is OAuth overkill if I am running single instance of django on a single server and I don't need to have a separate authentication server ?

Comment: It depends on your project.. best consult the documentation for pros & cons

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-rest-auth Django rest auth seems reasonable to me..

Comment: What if project is a simple online shop running on a single server. Do I still need OAuth ?

Comment: That's not a question anyone could possibly answer here.. Also I might remind you that it's possible to accept answers or upvote them..